# Vue Child is not loaded after route enter

Tags: vue.js, routes, parent-child

This is my router structure

```
{
  path: '/',
  name: 'home',
  component: Home
},
{
  path: '/user/:id',
  name: 'user',
  component: User,
  children: [
    {
      path: '',
      name: 'page',
      component: Page
    },
    .....
}
```

I used this in **Home.vue** to redirect (/user/12345)

```
    <router-link
        :to="{
            name: 'user',
            params: {id: user.userId}
            }"
    >
```

When I clicked this link in home page, it routes correct path however I can not render child component (**Page.vue**) However when I reload the page, child component is loaded successfully. (url is still same) 
There is an only rendering issue when I click the link on the homepage. How can I get rid of this. Thanks in advance.

**User.vue**

```
<template>
<div>
    <NavDrawer/>
    <router-view></router-view>
</div>
</template>
```

**Edit:** Any help will be so beneficial for me. Thanks

Comment: Could you show how you implement the Page Component please?

Comment: What do you mean by that ? I added User.vue Is this the thing that you are asking ? By using router-view I am rendering all children pages.

Comment: If you're trying to visualize the `Page,` why not redirecting to `page` route?

Comment: @AndreyPopov are you asking why not redirecting to page instead of routing user.vue on home.vue ?

Comment: I am asking why you have `:to="{ name: 'user'` instead of `:to="{ name: 'page'`?

Comment: I have 5-6 children of user.vue. I put sidebar and user related data inside it. (this are common data and I am rendering on all children pages) And using children pages I am rendering different data from each other with common data (from user.vue)